# MDADM did not kick off rebuild after a disk is inserted

Tags: linux, mdadm

I am new to Linux software RAID. I constructed a RAID6 with 6 hot-swappable SATA disks. I tested the failure scenario by unplugging 1 disk. The OS removed the devices from /dev and mdadm showed that the array was degraded. This is expected. However, when I put the disk back, although the OS reinstated the device name, the mdadm still showed that it is removed. I have to issue a command to add this drive in order to kick off the rebuild.

Since mdadm knows that a disk is removed, I expected that it will rebuild the array when a new disk is inserted. But this is not what expected. So my question is - is it possible to to kick off the soft RAID rebuild whenever a new disk is inserted at the same location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Automatic sync is limited to spare devices. It is of limited practical use to expect a disappeared drive to come back without manual intervention. If the device (or its connection) has become unreliable then a time consuming sync may not even be what you want. If this is important to you then you may regularly check via cron for such strange occurrences or trigger the appropriate mdadm action via udev.